# Change language to JSX in Visual Studio Code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code now [supports JSX on 0.8 version](https://code.visualstudio.com/Updates#_languages-jsx-colorization), but looks like the only way to activate it is with a `.jsx` file extension. It is not on the list to change the language mode manually, the nearest option is `JavaScriptReact`, but it doesn't parse the JSX tags.

I'm in a project with a lot of `.js` files with JSX and I can't change it.

Is there any other way to use JSX syntax without the `.jsx` extension?

Comment: See discussion here https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/140

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Change your user settings or workspace settings as below:

```
// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
}
```

Note: You might need to restart VSCode.

Comment: Works, did not even had to restart! Thanks

Comment: It helps even in the runtime! Thanks a lot!

Comment: What file and where?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `,` -> User or Workspace Settings

Comment: That turns EVERY js file into react files, even non-react js files like node modules. Maybe not the best way...

Comment: @PaulinTrognon if you don't want all js files into react files you can change the regex. For instance you could change all files that ends with _.react.js_ to react. For that change `*.js` to `*.react.js`.

Answer (score 11):

I would feel the below is the easiest way of formatting the code

Click on the bottom right on VS Code Editor where it says Javascript.

You will see an option to Select the language Mode, here you can search for JavaScriptReact and select. That's it. This should solve your problem.

1.[image: Check if JavascriptReact is selected??]
[image]

Comment: This question came from a time were this option did not existed yet. Right now it is as simple as you said.

Comment: Why don't I see this at the bottom of my vs editor?  I have the latest update of vs community and the latest version of react installed. and all extensions updated.

Instead I see a line showing one compile error and left/right arrow to go through errors and an 'add to source control github line in blue.

Comment: It worked for me, but why simple Javascript did not work?

Answer (score 7):

I could do it, but "not React JS files" are also show with JavaScriptReact mode.

1. open file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\plugins\vs.language.javascript\syntaxes\javascriptreact.json
   (probably, need to open with administrator privileges.)
2. change "jsx" to "js" in array "fileTypes".
3. restart app, close opened js files, and reopen.

Comment: For anyone else wondering, on Mac the path is: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScriptReact.tmLanguage

Comment: It worked for me. on Mac, added "js" also to the array list in this file:  /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScriptReact.t‌​mLanguage                                                                               `<array>
  <string>jsx</string>
  <string>js</string>
 </array>`

Comment: for Version 0.10.1 on Windows10, file to edit is changed. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\javascript\package.json`. and add `".js"` to `contributes.languages[0].extensions`.

Comment: @KoheiSugimura your solution worked but I also had to remove .js from contributes.languages[1].extensions and then it worked!

Answer (score 6):

Took me a while to figure this out but – JSX is already part of Emmet – which is part of VS Code. I've told Emmet to also (additionally) make JSX snippets available in regular JS files.

Just put this in your settings file:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {
    "javascript": "jsx"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Although Dionys' answer works there is a better way to do this in more recent versions of Visual Studio Code.

Go to `File>Prefrences>Settings` and then scroll down and find "Emmet" open the tab and you should see the following text

```
  // Enable Emmet abbreviations in languages that are not supported by default. Add a 
  mapping here between the language and emmet supported language.
  //  E.g.: {"vue-html": "html", "javascript": "javascriptreact"}
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {},
```

So just follow the instructions and add `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" }` on the json at the right panel ( which will overwrite the user settings ).

Comment: Thank you. Thank works without any of Dionys' side effect.

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [VS Code extension that allows `.js` files to be treated as `.jsx` files](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/eg2.js-is-jsx).

Unfortunately the readme for the extension also warns:

> when you install this extension you will loose all the existing language support provided for .js files

Fortunately VS Code is now very close to [adopting Salsa](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/user_ed/archive/2016/01/11/visual-studio-code-new-features-4-language-improvements-javascript-typescript-jsx-amp-tsx.aspx), which means soon the js-is-jsx issue should be completely resolved.

Comment: The link 500s and the plugin is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

Click on the **bottom right** on VS Code Editor where it says **Javascript**. You will see an option to *Select the language Mode*, here you can search for **JavaScriptReact** and select.
**That's it.**

Answer (score 0):

1-Press F1 (in Visual Studio Code)

2-Type "extension" in the appearing text field

3-Pick "Extensions: Install Extension"

3-Type "ext install jsx"

4- install JS JSX Snippets

5-Restart Visual Studio Code

Answer (score -2):

Just install an extension:

- Press F1 (in Visual Studio Code)
- Type "extension" in the appearing text field
- Pick "Extensions: Install Extension"
- Type "ext install jsx"
- Restart Visual Studio Code

Source:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery?pub=TwentyChung&ext=jsx
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/TwentyChung.jsx

Comment: Does this work for *.js files? I tried installing this and it doesn't seem to help with errors on the xml style stuff.

Comment: This extension appears to be a wrapper around a TextMate JSX.tmLanguage file. As the person who posted the question already pointed out, VSCode already supports highlighting JSX, they just need to do so on a JS file rather than only JSX. Therefore, installing this extension may not be helpful.

Comment: Yes this extension does not actually do anything as far as I can tell. Also I cannot figure out how to contact the guy who made it. I'd love to use vsCode for my react dev (webstorm sucks in comparison IMO)... Any one else got any good ideas?

Answer (score -6):

Try using link on Mac or Linux.

```
ln -s index.ios.js index.ios.jsx
```