# JsHint prompting an error about missing a semicolon in react syntax

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jshint

[Exact image of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DoJr.png)

I am not sure why this happens in my visual studio code environment.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    AppBar,
    ToolBar,
    Typography,
} from '@material-ui/core';

const AppHeader = () => {
    `<AppBar position="static"></AppBar>`
}
```

Also this is a standard react app. I just used the `create-react-app` and ran `yarn start` then I went into the src folder and made a file called `AppHeader.js` and typed that line of code into it. I am running all the latest versions by the way.

Comment: Try removing the braces or putting a return statement inside the braces and before the JSX code in `AppHeader`: const AppHeader = `() => \`<AppBar position="static"></AppBar>\`;` or `const AppHeader = () => { return \`<AppBar position="static"></AppBar>\`; }`. Do note that you are returning a string and not a component.

Comment: adding a semicolon to the end did not work nor did the return statement

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the point in defining a function that has a string in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AppHeader` function is incorrect. Since you are using an arrow function with curly braces, you *must* include the keyword `return` for the component to be used.

simply change it to

```
const AppHeader = () => (
  <AppBar position="static"></AppBar>
);
```

to fix your issue. Note the parens instead of curly braces, and the trailing semicolon.

Comment: This worked to fix the AppBar but then when I added some more code I got a new error within the same part. 

`const AppHeader = () => (
    <AppBar position="static">
        <ToolBar>
            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit">
                Okta CRUD React App
            </Typography>
        </ToolBar>
    </AppBar>   
)`

the error says `unclosed regular expression` and starts at the front of the closing tag `</Typography>`

Comment: @adarian You need to parse your JSX code into javascript. Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832264/change-language-to-jsx-in-visual-studio-code#37592711

Comment: I just edited the settings.json file in my user workspace with the following code and nothing changed. `// Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    }
}`

Comment: @adarian if you're still having issues, consider asking a new question