# visual studio code React does not recognize html

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code

as you see, the HTML content is not colorful, and it cannot autocomplete HTML tag

[image]

Comment: [Have you tried this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832264/change-language-to-jsx-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways to do that.

1) You could manually set the syntax to "Javascript React".

For that click on "Javascript" on the bottom right of your screen:

[image]

Then simply enter "react" and select it. After that you should have autocomplete for the html parts inside your render functions.

2) You can instruct VSCode to always open `.js` files as "javascriptreact". For that go to your settings and copy `files.associations` over to your local settings. Make sure it looks something like this and save:

`"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}`

Note on that one: This will always set the syntax to "javascriptreact" when you open `.js` files and might not always be what you want. A better solution would be to generally name react files as `myfile.jsx`. This way vscode will automatically set the syntax to "javascriptreact".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- **Save the file as .jsx ie (App.jsx) instead of .js**

> This is because you are saving the file as .js ie App.js.JavaScript files cannot understand HTML tags.
>
> Another alternative is you can save in (.js) but your web pack should be configured in such a way that it should transpile it into .jsx.
> For doing refer this - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Answer (score -1):

React understand javascript xml only.